# How to prove that there exists a point c ∈ [a, b] for which f(c) = f(b−c+a).

Tags: functions, continuity

> **Definition:** Let $f:[a,b] → \Bbb R$ be a continuous function.

---

Assume that $f(b) = a$ and $f (a) = b$.

> **Question:**  Prove that there exists a point
>   $c ∈ [a, b] $ for which $f (c) = f (b − c + a)$.

Can someone help me with the proof?

Comment: Can you not just choose $c$ such that $c=b-c+a$? I.e., $c=\frac{a+b}{2}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $g(x)=f(b+a-x)-f(x)$. We want to find a zero of $g$. We know $g(a)=f(b)-f(a)$ and $g(b)=f(a)-f(b)$. Note that $g(a)=-g(b)$. Then apply intermediate value theorem to $g$.